# Vertical scrollbar covering the last column data of jtable(last column data is right aligned)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I am using a jtable which have 8 rows by default.  When I add a new row using a button click a vertical scrollbar comes into picture and covers up my data of last column in jtable which is right aligned. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS)` on the `JScrollPane`. This will leave room for the scroll bar when (if) it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to give your table a little bit more space to account for the addition of a scroll bar.  You will need to possibly mess with the preferredSize.